# How can I check new_record? of association saved in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am sorry but how I can check if saved association is new_record?. Because either after_save or before_save is called after saving association.

```
class Children
   belongs_to parent
   after_create :check_new_record_of_parent
   # before_save :check_parent_saved   # call this method also not work

   private 
   def check_new_record_of_parent
     parent.new_record?   # not work because parent is saved before this method called
   end

   def check_parent_saved
      parent.nil? 0 : 1
   end
end

class Parent
    has_many children
end
```

I call children.update_attributes(nested_form) instead of children.save;

Comment: Are you saying you can have multiple parents per children?

Comment: there's something off here, for a children, parent should be present and your children will be saved as `parent.childrens.new(nested_form)`, how does your controller look? Why do you want to check that? a more context will help in finding alternate solution.

Comment: @Ho Man No, one children has only one parent.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon it is children.update_attributes(nested_form). I want to send email to admin if a new parent is created new in db. The parent and children created through form in view.

Comment: @Hung Show the action in which you process the parent/children data from your form. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def before_save
  @was_a_new_record = new_record?
  return true
end

def after_save
 if @was_a_new_record
   ...
 end
end
```

Try this and see if it works or not.